# How to read large gzip csv files from azure storage in memory in aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to transform large gzip csv files(>3 Gigs) from azure storage blob by loading it to pandas dataframe in AWS Lambda function.

Local machine with 16 gigs is able to process my files but it gives memory error *"errorType": "MemoryError",* while executing in aws lambda, since lambda has max memory is 3 Gb.

Is there any way of reading and processing those large data in memory in aws lambda. Just to mention I tried stream way as well but no luck.

Below is my sample code-

```
from azure.storage.blob import *
import pandas as pd
import gzip

blob = BlobClient(account_url="https://" + SOURCE_ACCOUNT + ".blob.core.windows.net",
                          container_name=SOURCE_CONTAINER,
                          blob_name=blob_name,
                          credential=SOURCE_ACCT_KEY)
    
data = blob.download_blob()
data = data.readall()
    
unzipped_bytes = gzip.decompress(data)
unzipped_str = unzipped_bytes.decode("utf-8")
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(unzipped_str), usecols=req_columns,low_memory=False)
```

Comment: Why lambda? It does not seem as a good choice for this task due to its limitations. And what about processing time? Lambda can run only for 15 minutes? Would this be enough even if you could load your data to it?

Comment: If you don't need the whole file's context for transformation, maybe you could decompress in chunks somehow. Maybe [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jiankaiwang/f5056a34bbbf595c9553efb36aff64ec) could be helpful, line 31 in particular.

Comment: @Marcin What else do you suggest if not Lambda , I don't want to go ECS cluster way before exhausting the in memory streaming of data. I know the limitation of lambda's execution and memory that's why I asked it. I know people are processing large file in lambda vis step function for S3 files, but azure blob which is in compressed format is my problem. Please suggest any solution if you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using chunks and read data by n-rows per one time:

```py
for chunk in pd.read_csv("large.csv", chunksize=10_000):
    print(chunk)
```

Although, I’m not sure about compressed files. In worst case you can uncompress data and then read by chunks.

Comment: Dana your suggestion is correct, but as I mentioned in my post I'm doing that bit in my local ans able to process it w/o any problem. Thanks